# I think i committed too much through git and i dont want to delete the files on my computer

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal

[what my current situation looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z10h.png)

Vs code kept telling me that I had a lot of unsaved changes through it's built in git. I didn't really know what it was about(considering I committed all the changes of the projects I worked on) So today I got frustrated, opened the terminal, and tried to do a hard commit by using:
git add -A && git commit -m "Your Message"
after that git was running for a good 5-10 mins of just running a bunch of stuff, for some things I received a permission denied and when I started actually looking at the files git was processing and it looked like all the applications i have on my computer? Im not understanding why VS code would have random stuff i recently downloaded being considered as 'unsaved changes'. I ignored it for a bit until I started to work on a new project and I received the message again, when I went to go look this time it was a bunch of random stuff that looked like it just tried to process files on my computer not related to code but i thought about deleting all changes cause i felt like it was unnecessary to keep them if i was going to keep getting the same message but i dont know that if i press delete will it just delete all those files on my computer????
I dont really understand what i did or anything for that matter. I can provide any clarification and the picture is what i can currently see with vs code i can also show my terminal if that helps but you cant see anything i personally typed just everything that came after.

Comment: Looks like you did git init at the top level of your computer and put the whole computer under git control.

Comment: is there a way to un-do it? i didnt start using it until recently so i think vs code may have done it when i started using vs code before i even knew what git was and not sure how or why it would've done that. but that does explain a lot of my issues with git

Comment: i think i fixed it! thank you for your insight it actually really helped!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init